# react typescript Target requires 1 element(s) but source may have fewer

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, react-typescript

I am trying to set the type for my data but getting this error `Type 'UseQueryResult<unknown, unknown>[]' is not assignable to type '[{ data: { settingTypeId: string; settingValue: string; }; }]'. Target requires 1 element(s) but source may have fewer.`

On my console `channelSettingTypes` data is like this :

```
[{data: {settingTypeId: 'ActFollow', settingValue: 'BlY'}
dataUpdatedAt: 1655203914273
error: null
errorUpdatedAt: 0
failureCount: 0
isError: false},...]
```

and my interface is like the below type

```
interface Tabs {
  channelSettingTypes: [
    {
      data: {settingTypeId: string; settingValue: string};
    },
  ];
}
```

Comment: `UseQueryResult` Might help knowing what that is.

Answer (score 0):

The UseQueryResult data type would need to be setup like this to allow 0+ items in the list

```
type oneData = {settingTypeId: string; settingValue: string}

type UseQueryResult = channelSettingTypes: oneData[]
```

so instead of having a type "UseQueryResult" set with an array of objects, you set a data type for one single object first, then have set the data type for an array of the single objects.